# LVM disappeared after reboot!

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, lvm, data-recovery

I had an PV, VG, and LV on `/dev/sda5` partition. Dealt with some corruption on the filesystem with `xfs_repair` until all filesystems were mountable with no errors.

After rebooting the node, the pv,vg,and lvm were all completely gone.
`pvdisplay` no results
`vgdisplay` no results
`lvdisplay` no results.

`lsblk` shows type `part` for `/dev/sda5` (the supposed PV). Meanwhile `fdisk` shows type `Linux LVM`.

`file -s /dev/sda5` outputs `data`

**pvck outputs**:

`Warning pv_header offset unexpected for first mda` and `pv_header.pv_uuid invalid format`

Comment: did you perhaps accidentally run `xfs_repair` on /dev/sda5 instead of the LV? Other than that, it's relatively rare for XFS to have to be repaired with `xfs_repair`. Is your /dev/sda maybe simply broken?

Comment: I ran xfs_repair on the lv filesystems inside of the partition.
example `xfs_repair /dev/vgname/lvname`

Comment: then chances are your hard drive is losing data, best explanation I have, and that affected at the very least the metadata block of your physical volume :(

Comment: So well, attach at least `lsblk`, `blkid` into the question. Also, do you have anything useful in /etc/lvm (e.g. VG metadata backups, latest version and so on)?

Comment: content is not accessible in /etc/lvm because the server cannot boot since /boot was an lv inside of the disk. Currently I'm troubleshooting via a live OS boot

Comment: To recover your data, first do a full dd backup copy of the disk. If you know the exact boundaries of your PV, VG and LV and also the exact boundaries (byte exact!) you might recreate those things at the backup disk with using the exact same parameters. PS make sure your backup drive is the exact same harddisk drive type, with same byte size. Otherwise contact a data recovery company.